# nVLC wrapper not streaming video

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, vlc, libvlc

i have searched the net for a good .net VLC wrapper and i found this excellent one [nVLC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC) it contains interfaces to many of the features that VLC have and i read how to stream a **file** or the stream from **directshow**, but i still have a problem that the file is being read but no data is being streamed ??
it can be downloaded from here [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/nVLC/)
my code:

```
var input="C:\\1.mp4";
var argument="sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5004,ttl=40}:sout-all:sout-keep";
var factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMediaFromFile>(input, argument); //tried IMedia and got the same results
IVideoPlayer player = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>(); // tried IPlayer and got the same results
media.Parse(false);
player.Open(media);
player.Play();
```

VLC Opens the media file and i can see and here the video but when trying to capture the stream using VLC i get nothing.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues trying to get nvlc to transcode a video stream.  I only got it working once I split the arguments up into separate strings.

Try

```
var argument= new Object[] { "sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=5004,ttl=40}"
                            ,":sout-all"
                            ,":sout-keep" };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 IMediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        IMedia media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(@"udp://@127.0.0.1:5004");
        IVideoPlayer player = factory.CreatePlayer<IVideoPlayer>();
        player.WindowHandle = panel1.Handle;
        player.Open(media);
        player.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i need to accomplish reading from file and then restream it to udp